# Adjusting div to be between the left side of body, and another div with a margin of auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like my `ad` div to be exactly between the left side of the body, and the `middle` div. How would I accomplish that?

```css
body {
border: 1px solid black; 
}
#middle {
border: 1px solid black;   
margin: auto;  
width: 50px;
height: 100px; 
} 
#ad {
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;    
width: 50px;
height: 100px; 
}
```

```html
<div id = "ad"> ad </div>
<div id = "middle"> middle </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly between"? I am afraid you need to specify the exact layout you want.

Comment: @Joy I mean the ad div with a margin of auto, that's between the left side of the body, and the center div.

Comment: the problem is, that your `margin: auto` is orientated at the other elements (your parent element). You could achieve this but it will be hacky...better define no-relative sizes or use a kind of responsive design here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this layout with [**flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), combining [**`auto` margins**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) with an invisible flex item.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box ad"> ad </div>
<div class="box middle"> middle </div>
<div class="box invisible"> right </div><!-- invisible -->
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.invisible { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; visibility: hidden;  }
.middle    { margin-left: auto; }
.ad        { margin-left: auto; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/edeje4f2/)

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*